# socket.io flashsocket not working

Tags: websocket, socket.io, flashsocket

The Websocket or XHR transport works just fine.

But not the Flashsocket.

The console shows this:

```
   debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/flashsocket/kavSuw7LSfrHmQBM1C8D
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client kavSuw7LSfrHmQBM1C8D
   debug - client authorized for
   debug - client authorized
   info  - handshake authorized UPai64qwBoTlGL2X1C8E
```

then nothing more... I set the program to emit msg every second, nothing sent.

Then I use chrome to access http://domain.com:10843/, it shows this:

```
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

I think it is not blocked... So what's wrong here?

PS. Server is Windows Server 2008

Answer (score 1):

Try testing on IE8 or 9. It has been noted that flashsocket will not work on Chrome even if it is the only transport listed. Use ["websocket","flashsocket"] for best results, and if you get a websocket when you weren't expecting one, consider it a happy surprise :-).

Comment: I've tried on IE 6-9 version, still not working at all. In debug info, the flashsocket connection had been created, just no more data could be transferred.

Comment: I'm also getting the same issue with socket.io 0.9.14+... Could be a bug.

Comment: It was working for me with flashsocket on IE8 and 9, and I was using 0.9.14. I just dug up that code and I see I commented out "io.enable('browser client gzip');" with a remark that it "crashed".